# obtain largest vector from n input files MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm developing a program that reads data from an excel file, it saves the data regarding to numbers in the variable num then it determines which vector from the data read is the largest one.
I want to expand this code for n number of input files in an efficient way (not read and compare file by file).
any recommendations on how to achieve this?

Suppose I want this code to work for file names finger1.xlsx to finger100.xlsx

```
filename='finger1.xlsx';
[num1,txt1] = xlsread(filename);
filename='finger2.xlsx';
[num2,txt2] = xlsread(filename);
filename='finger3.xlsx';
[num3,txt3] = xlsread(filename);
filename='finger4.xlsx';
[num4,txt4] = xlsread(filename);
filename='finger5.xlsx';
[num5,txt5] = xlsread(filename);

if(length(num1)>length(num2))
    parent=num1;
    rank=1;
else
    parent=num2;
    rank=2;
end
if(length(num3)>length(parent))
    parent=num3;
    rank=3;
end
if(length(num4)>length(parent))
    parent=num4;
    rank=4;
end  

if(length(num5)>length(parent))
    parent=num5;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a loop and change the name of the file based on the loop variable `i`.

```
    filename = sprintf('finger%d.xlsx', i);
```

If you do not want to compare file by file, you might store all the data from all the files and then use `max` to find the largest one.

Comment: wow thank you! great answer. regarding max, can I store each vector in a cell and then obtain the maximum vector?